# How to add system intents (e.g. actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS_FINISHED) to the Google Assistant Action Builder

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

How can I add a system intent to the scene in the Action Builder?

E.g. I want to add one of the media intents: `actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS_STOPPED`, `actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS_PAUSED`,...

When you try to add one of these to the scene, you will get the error:

> Name can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores. The name also must start with a letter.

If you try to add it without the "actions.intent." part, e.g. `MEDIA_STATUS_STOPPED` it will be treated as a user's custom intent. And because of it, it won't handle any callback for the Media object state changes.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/intents) is silent about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to add these Intents under the "User intent handling" section of the Scene. But these aren't user intents - these are system intents that have been pre-defined. So instead you add them in the "Error and status handling" section.

[image: Error and status handling section]

When you do, the pane on the right will let you select a System Intent to setup processing for.

[image: System Intent pane]

You can then select the System Intent from the drop-down menu, including MEDIA_STATUS_STOPPED, etc.

[image: System Intent drop down menu]

Once you have, you can then setup how you want to handle that System Intent (calling a webhook, sending prompts, and/or transitioning to another scene).

[image: Intent handling]

You can then repeat this, as necessary, for any other media status system intents.

Comment: Thank you for that! I solved it differently, using gactions CLI and editing the scene's yaml:

`- handler:
    webhookHandler: mediaStatusHandler
  intent: actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS_FINISHED
- handler:
    webhookHandler: mediaStatusHandler
  intent: actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS_PAUSED
- handler:
    webhookHandler: mediaStatusHandler
  intent: actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS_STOPPED
- handler:
    webhookHandler: mediaStatusHandler
  intent: actions.intent.MEDIA_STATUS_FAILED`

 It required me much more efforts to do the same thing :-)

Comment: If an answer has helped - accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated. If you have another solution, posting it as a separate answer (and accepting that answer) is encouraged.